# Is angular universal providing JIT or AOT compiling?

Tags: angular

Angular universal is providing server-side rendering but for compiling which one is provided default support in angular?

Comment: This is a good start: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Universal uses JIT but you can use modules to change that too AOT for better performance.

Explanation: 
Angular uses AOT to compile TS to JS and JIT is used for compiling JS to Runtime in your browser.

Long answer:
Angular Universal is all about the server-side rendering of the initial page load. It pushes the initial loading of the Angular application to the server for improved performance. AOT (Ahead of Time compilation) is about compiling the TypeScript down to JavaScript outside of the normal process Angular Uses - JIT (Just In Time compilation). JIT compiles the TypeScript whenever the page is served. AOT is the module used to pre-compile the page separately. AOT is better for performance and should be used in production. JIT is easier to work with during development (because you don’t have to separately compile and update the deployed files each time you make a change).

Comment: Can you give brief detail?

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation.

Angular cannot be understood by the browser directly, Angular applications require a compilation process before they can run in a browser.

The Angular Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler converts your Angular HTML and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code during the build phase before the browser downloads and runs that code. Compiling your application during the build process provides a faster rendering in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Generally angular will use JIT for development mode eg: `ng serve` and AOT for production builds eg: `ng build --production`

Angular universal is always using AOT builds as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler actually replaces the browser and parses the HTML for you.

> The main purpose of the Angular Compiler -> ***transforming your HTML
>   templates into optimized TypeScript code which creates an equivalent
>   DOM structure***

Based from the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#angular-compilation):

> Angular offers two ways to compile your application:
>
> 1. Just-in-Time (JIT), which compiles your app in the browser at runtime.
> 2. Ahead-of-Time (AOT), which compiles your app at build time.

**In Angular 2**:

**JIT:**
Parsing the component templates every time the user opens the web page, a part that transforms HTML templates into runnable code, this is a major setback lead to AOT. In short, this will run every time for every user at runtime.

**AOT:**
Runs the compile step during the build process instead of inside the browser, so when you build your project for production, the compiler can disappear completely from the output, saving precious CPU cycles when the page loads in the user’s browser. In short, this will run once at build time.

In **Angular 5+**, you will able to neglect JIT and go full AOT due to Faster rendering, Fewer asynchronous requests, Smaller Angular framework download size, Detect template errors earlier and Better Security. Therefore, for the latest Angular version which is 7, AOT now is the best recommended compiler than the JIT.

> Note: We must know that JIT compilation is the default but we can
>   switch to AOT for better performance.